# Django ORM query with multiple join fields

Tags: sql, django

How could I make this mysql query into django ORM?

```
SELECT search_products.model, search_products.year, search_products.size, search_avg_price.estimated_price
FROM search_products
left JOIN search_avg_price
ON search_products.model=search_avg_price.model and search_products.size=search_avg_price.size and search_products.year=search_avg_price.year
```

I have already tried

```
latest_products = Products.objects.all().prefetch_related("avg_price")
```

but this is translated by django as

```
SELECT `search_products`.`id`, `search_products`.`size`, `search_products`.`year`, , `search_products`.`model`, `search_products`.`avg_price_id`
FROM `search_products`
```

and

```
latest_products = Products.objects.all().select_related("avg_price")
```

This is translated by django as:

```
SELECT `search_products`.`id`, `search_products`.`size`, `search_products`.`year`, , `search_products`.`model`, `search_products`.`avg_price_id`, `search_avg_price`.`id`, `search_avg_price`.`model`, `search_avg_price`.`size`, `search_avg_price`.`year`, `search_avg_price`.`estimated_price` 
FROM `search_products` 
INNER JOIN `search_avg_price` ON ( `search_products`.`avg_price_id` = `search_avg_price`.`id` )
```

if I run the above SQL in the database I get the proper result...

Edit: Models and views

```
class Avg_price(models.Model):
 model = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
 size= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 year= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 estimated_price= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Products(models.Model):
 product_id =models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 link_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
 model = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
 size= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 price= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 year= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
 type=models.ForeignKey(Type)
 avg_price = models.ForeignKey(Avg_price)

 def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
   return self.location
```

Template

```
{% if latest_products %}
  {% for product in latest_products %}
  <ul>
    <li id="col_one">
      <h5>{{product.avg_price.estimated_price}}</h5>
      <h5>{{product.model}}</h5>
```

Comment: You don't want `select_related` or `prefetch_related` for this, you want to use filter to tie to the other model, assuming a Foreign Key or Many to Many relationship. Can you post your model code?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass tables list to method *extra()* and put conditions from ON of your sql query to *where* section in *extra()*

```
Product.objects.extra(
    tables=['search_avg_price'],
    where=[
        '"search_products"."model"="search_avg_price"."model"',
        '"search_products"."size"="search_avg_price"."size"',
        '"search_products"."year"="search_avg_price"."year"'
   ]
)
```

read more about extra:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Comment: Is there a way to access values of the `search_avg_price` table joined with `.extra()`? Official docs are very brief. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try the query like this:

```
qs = Product.objects.filter(
    avg_price__model__isnull=True).filter(
    avg_price__size__isnull=True).filter(
    avg_price__year__isnull=True).values_list(
    'model', 'year', 'size', 'avg_price__estimated_price')
```

To test:

```
print(qs.query)
```

Explanation:

From your Product model, you are accessing the `ForeignKey` each time on `avg_price` and the relative field in that model that you want to be `NULL` each time when you return the query based on a `LEFT JOIN`. Here's the documentation on look ups that span relationships:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Then `values_list` let's you specify which values to return.  Here's the documentation on values_list:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list

Comment: I tried and got the error: "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'avg_price.estimated_price' into field". It seems django is not being able to see the other table... Also I would need to show all results from table products and add the result from table avg_price whenever present (mach of year, model and size)... thanks for the help

Comment: How about with `avg_price__estimated_price` instead of `avg_price.estimated_price`?

Comment: The resulting query is different from the one I want to built... SELECT `search_productsmodel`, `search_products`.`year`, `search_products`.`size`, `search_avg_price`.`estimated_price` 
FROM `search_products` INNER JOIN `search_avg_price` ON ( `search_products`.`avg_price_id` = `search_avg_price`.`id` ) 
WHERE (`search_avg_price`.`model` IS NULL AND `search_avg_price`.`size` IS NULL AND `search_avg_price`.`year` IS NULL)